# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Error in list of function arguments: ')' not recognized. Unable to parse query text

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

```
SELECT Name, 
  SUM(IIf([Date] = DateAdd('d', - 7, DATE ()),  PBal,0)) AS Opening, 
  SUM(IIf([Date] = DateAdd('d', - 7, DATE ()), NetAmount,0) ) AS DAY1,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-6,Date()),NetAmount ,0))AS DAY2,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-5,Date()),NetAmount ,0))AS DAY3,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-4,Date()),NetAmount,0 ))AS DAY4,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-3,Date()),NetAmount,0 ))AS DAY5,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-2,Date()),NetAmount,0 ))AS DAY6,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-1,Date()),NetAmount,0 ))AS DAY7,
  (Day1+Day2+Day3+Day4+Day5+Day6+Day7) AS Billtotal,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-7,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash1,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-6,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash2,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-5,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash3,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-4,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash4,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-3,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash5,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-2,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash6,
  sum(IIf([Date] =DateAdd('d',-1,Date()),(NetAmount-BBal),0)) AS Cash7,
  Cash1+Cash2+Cash3+Cash4+Cash5+Cash6 +Cash7) as CashPaid,
  (Billtotal-CashPaid) + Opening AS Currentbalance 
FROM Customer 
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: I'm a human, but I feel the "Unable to parse query text" thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Date()` isn't a function. You want `GetDate()`
2. The first parameter in `dateadd` doesn't take quotes : `dateadd(d, -4, getdate())`
3. And if you're not using SQL 2012, `IIF` isn't a function.

You may find a `pivot` on a `datediff` provides a simpler query.